# Evaluating partial sum of $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{x}a^{x-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Show that $$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{x} a^{x-1} = \frac{1}{1-a}$$
>   where $a \in (0,1)$.

Comment: Where does the index $n$ go?

Answer (score 1):

We have that $$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}a^{x}=\frac{1}{1-a}$$ where $|a|<1$. Taking the derivative in respect to $a$ we get $$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}xa^{x-1}=\frac{1}{(1-a)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

To approach this I first remind you about the geometric series:

$$\sum_{x = 0}^\infty a^x = \frac{1}{1 - a}$$

iff $|a| < 1$. If we restrict ourselves to the region of convergence then we are allowed to take derivatives:

$$\frac{d}{da} \Bigg[ \sum_{x = 0}^\infty a^x = \frac{1}{1 - a} \Bigg]$$

$$\sum_{x = 0}^\infty \frac{d}{da} a^x = \frac{1}{(1 - a)^2}$$

$$\sum_{x = 1}^\infty xa^{x - 1} = \frac{1}{(1 - a)^2}$$

where the sum shifts over by one each time a derivative is taken since the first term is a constant. You can argue that even if we have $x = 0 \implies xa^{x - 1} = 0$, but that introduces a singularity at $a = 0$ which we want to avoid.